# Checking for jumps on checkerboard

Tags: java, swing, object, paint

I am having a problem with my checkerboard that has been coded to check if there are possible legal jumps for red (the board is only coded assuming red is going down the board). My right jump logic is working but my left jump logic makes the checker think it is ok to jump on a black checker in the upper-right corner instead of the lower left. I put a yellow circle on each checker to see if the jump is possible.

[image]

If we assume the rows are 1-8 and the columns a-h then the marked checker on 7b is wrong. It should not be marked at all but it is checking the black checker in the upper right corner of it (6c). All red checkers do this. The checker on 6e is correct. It is looking to the lower right corner (7f) to see if there is a black there and an accompanying blank spot right after it. The red checker on 3f should be marked because there is a black checker in the lower left corner (4e) and an acompanying empty spot diagonally below it. The CheckRightJump method is fine but the CheckLeftMethod is wrong somehow.

If I reverse the board (put red going up) then the problem is mirrored. The left jump method works but the right doesn't.

```
  import java.applet.Applet;
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.util.Random;
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;
   import javax.swing.*;
   import javax.swing.event.*;

//**********************************************


public class Checkers extends JApplet
{
    private final int MAX_SIZE = 8; 
    private final int APP_WIDTH = 400;
    private final int APP_HEIGHT = 400;
    private final int MAXSIZE = 8;

    Square[][] sq;

    //Calls methods to draw the board, place the checkers
    // and find jumps
    public void paint(Graphics page)
    {

        setBackground(Color.white);
        fillBoard(page); // draws the method that will draw the checkers         
        placeCheckers(page, 7, Color.red);   //method to place the red checkers
        placeCheckers(page, 9, Color.black); //method to draw  black checkers
        CheckJumps(page);   //check if checkers can jump    
        setSize (APP_WIDTH,APP_HEIGHT);

    }

    public void fillBoard(Graphics page)
    {

        sq = new Square[8][8];

        int x,y;
        Color rg;

        for (int row = 0; row < MAXSIZE; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < MAXSIZE; col++)
            {
                x = row * (APP_WIDTH/MAXSIZE);
                y = col * (APP_HEIGHT/MAXSIZE);
                if ( (row % 2) == (col % 2) )
                    rg = Color.red;
                else
                    rg = Color.gray;
                    sq[row][col] = new Square (x, y, rg);  
                }

                for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
                    for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
                        sq[row][col].draw(page);
            }

    //Method to place checkers randomly on gray squares
    public void placeCheckers (Graphics page, int num_checkers, Color ncolor)
    {
        int count, row, col;
        int x, y;
        Circle c;

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (count = 0; count < num_checkers; count++)
        {
            do
            {
                row = rand.nextInt(8);
                col = rand.nextInt(8);
            } while (sq[row][col].getOccupy() || sq[row][col].getColor() != Color.gray);

            x = row * (APP_WIDTH/MAXSIZE);
            y = col * (APP_HEIGHT/MAXSIZE);

            c = new Circle (x, y, 50, ncolor);

            c.draw(page);

            sq[row][col].setOccupy(true);
            sq[row][col].setCheckerC(ncolor);
        } 

    }

    //********************************************************
    //Method to check for valid jumps and mark pieces
    //********************************************************
    public void CheckJumps (Graphics page) // Coded to check for red going down the board
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < sq[row].length; col++)
            { 
                if (col < 2 && sq[row][col].getOccupy() && 
                    sq[row][col].getCheckerC() == Color.red)
                    CheckRightJump(page, row, col);
                if (col > 5 && sq[row][col].getOccupy() && 
                    sq[row][col].getCheckerC() == Color.red)
                    CheckLeftJump(page, row, col);
                if (col > 1 && col < 6 && sq[row][col].getOccupy() && 
                    sq[row][col].getCheckerC() == Color.red)        
                {
                   CheckRightJump(page, row, col);
                   CheckLeftJump(page, row, col);
                }  

            }        
    }

    //Checks  valid right-hand jumps
    public void CheckRightJump (Graphics page, int row, int col)
    {
        Circle c;
        int x = row * (APP_WIDTH/MAXSIZE);
        int y = col * (APP_HEIGHT/MAXSIZE);

        if (sq[row+1][col+1].getOccupy() && 
            sq[row+1][col+1].getCheckerC() == Color.black && 
            !sq[row+2][col+2].getOccupy())
        {   
            c = new Circle (x + 15, y + 15, 20, Color.yellow);
            c.draw(page);  
        }    
    }

    //Checks valid left-hand jumps
    public void CheckLeftJump (Graphics page, int row, int col)
    {
        Circle c;
        int x = row * (APP_WIDTH/MAXSIZE);
        int y = col * (APP_HEIGHT/MAXSIZE);

        if (sq[row+1][col-1].getOccupy() && 
            sq[row+1][col-1].getCheckerC() == Color.black && 
            !sq[row+2][col-2].getOccupy())
        {   
            c = new Circle (x + 15, y + 15, 20, Color.yellow);
            c.draw(page);  
        }  
    } 

}//close checker class

//*******************************************************
//Shapes Interface
interface Shapes
{
    public void SetX(int newX);
    public void SetY(int newY);
    public int GetX();
    public int GetY();
}// close interface Shapes


//*******************************************************
//Class that represents a square on the board
//Each square has an x/y location, a size and some other variable to be determined by you

class Square 
{


    private int x, y = 0;  
    private Color c, checkerC;
    private boolean occupied;

    // constructor

    public Square (int x, int y, Color c)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void setX (int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getX ()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public void setY (int y)
    {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getY ()
    {
        return y;
    }

    public void setColor (Color c)
    {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public Color getColor ()
    {
        return c;
    }

    public void setOccupy (boolean occupied)
    {
        this.occupied = occupied;
    }

    public boolean getOccupy ()
    {
        return occupied;
    }

    public Color getCheckerC ()
    {
        return checkerC;
    }

    public void setCheckerC (Color checkerC)
    {
        this.checkerC = checkerC;
    }

    // setter and getters
    //equals method
    // toString method

    public void draw (Graphics page)
    {
        page.setColor(c);
        page.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);    

    } 
}//Close square class


//***********************************************************************
//Class to represent a checker - both black and white on the checkerboard
class Circle
{


    private int x,y;
    private int diameter;
    private Color c;

    public Circle (int x, int y, int diameter, Color c)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.diameter = diameter;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void setX (int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getX ()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public void setY (int y)
    {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getY ()
    {
        return y;
    }

    public void setColor (Color c)
    {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public Color getColor ()
    {
        return c;
    }

    public void setDiameter (int x)
    {
        diameter = x;
    }

    // a draw method to draw a circle

    public void draw (Graphics page)
    {
        page.setColor(c);
        page.fillOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: `.getOccupy()` if this returns "false" if you check positions outside of the checkerboard, then a jump to the right will be okay for the left stone.

Comment: It is very difficult to tell what your problem is -- I know you've described it, but I don't understand the description.  You talk about checkers in corners, but I don't know what corners you're talking about.  Possibly you can name the rows and columns (chess uses 1-8 and a-h), and then say "checker on c3 should not be able to jump to h6, but the computer thinks it is supposed to." and so forth.

Comment: I added more info using the chess notation. Let me know if that helped.

Comment: Since there are one or more things that are wrong, at least in terms of  naming (checkers should really have nothing to do with Graphics) I suggest rethinking and coming up with a cleaner design. Of course it might just be a one line typo you can narrow down.

Comment: As for the design, this is a template my professor gave us to use for class so I have to use this. Everything else works but this weird problem. Other than that, do you see any problems within this?

Comment: What is sq? Is it a 2D array of the board?

Comment: Yes. It's a 2d array of square objects that make up the checkerboard itself.

Comment: is it larger than the size of the board itself? It seems like you should be getting an array out of bounds exception when you check positions outside of the board as @Sebastian Hoffner mentioned earlier. Instead it seems to be returning that the square is not occupied which is why the checker at 7b is marked with a yellow spot.

Comment: No. I have Square sq = new Square[8][8] just for each square on the board. I don't see where I am checking positions outside the board. Row only checks from 0-6 and col checks from 0-7. I don't get any out of bounds error.

Comment: For 7B, you will have row = 6, col = 1. You call checkRightJump(page, 6, 1). Then you check that row + 1 (= 7), col + 1 (= 2) is occupied (it is), then you check that it's black (it is), then you check that row + 2 (=8) and col + 2 ( = 3) is occupied. There should not be a row 8. What does your getOccupy() method do? EDIT: Ah i just noticed your first for loop will keep this from happening.

Comment: Do you want me to put the rest of the code up?

Comment: Oh right, I didn't catch that either. 
From what we see it should work, so maybe your board is somehow wrong and returns unexpected values somewhere.

Comment: I put in everything now. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I think the problem is that you sometimes mix up x/y and rows/cols and the array accesses. I found out that e.g. 7b is in fact sq[1][6] opposed to the expected sq[6][1].

Try to use x for cols, y for rows, [rows][cols] and top left as 0/0. This way you should avoid most of those problems since you will have a common coordinate system (just with different scalings).

Also (unrelated to the question) you have an interface which is obviously for the Squares and Circles but you don't implement it there.

Comment: Words cannot describe how thankful I am to you right now. I understand where it went wrong now. Also, the interface was put there by my teacher in this template but we never used it.